# Creating a webpage that accepts input values and adds the textboxes as shown based on the values of the values of the user

Tags: javascript, html, web-development-server

The issue with this one is, when I'm writing the number (as a user) it isn't showing up in the text field plus, it's not taking more than 9 numbers as an input.
If anyone knows what's wrong or where I'm lacking please do help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" width="20" id="answer" value="0" oninput="sum()">Number of members (max. 100)<br>
    <a href="#">Fill Details</a><br>
    <script>   
        function sum()
        {
            n = parseInt(document.getElementById('answer').value);
            str='<input type="text" width="20" id="answer" oninput="sum()">Number of members (max.20)<br><a href="#">Fill Details</a><br>';
            "20" class="n1"><br>'
            }
            document.body.innerHTML=str;   
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: Check your javascript function. Your str variable is cut off and you got a snippet of plaintext under its declaration, as well as an extraenous closing parenthises.

Comment: I just tried this in-browser, you'll find that this still won't work as your code replaces the input with a new one and thus deletes its content. (Ideally, don't use document.body.innerHTML())